# How do you initiate Realm in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, realm

I needed to initialize `Realm` from `fragment` but I get the following `warning`:

```
Required: Context
Found: Context
```

Code:

```
class MyRealm: Fragment() {

    private lateinit var realm : Realm

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_realm, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        Realm.init(context)

        val configuration = RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .name("MyRealm.db")
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .schemaVersion(0)
            .build()

        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(configuration)

        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    }

}
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Opening and closing the realm within try/catch block is recommended

```
    try {
 Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
 //Use the realm instance

}catch(Exception e){
  //handle exceptions
}finally {
    realm.close();
}
```

Also check for minSdkVersion >= 19 and Java >= 7
You can go through the official documentation for more details https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#closing-realms

Also use `getActivity()` in place of `(context)`.
The activity is a `context` (since `Activity` extends `Context`).

Comment: I transferred the code to the `Fragment`'s host `Activity` and it's all working now. Thanks anyway.